# swift UITableView scrolls up when keyboard appears but I can't see the top cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a ViewController with a TableView and a textView. I'm using the following code so that when the keyboard shows up, it pushes the textView and Tableview up.

**bindToKeyboard**

```
extension UIView {

    func bindToKeyboard(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
            #selector(UIView.keyboardWillChange(_:)), name:
            UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        let duration = notification.userInfo!
        [UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
            as! UInt
        let curFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]
            as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let targetFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
            as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = targetFrame.origin.y - curFrame.origin.y

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options:
            UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
                self.frame.origin.y += deltaY

        },completion: {(true) in
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the top cells in the tableView, i can't scroll down to display them unless i close the keyboard. I've been searching for possible code samples to fix this but I can't seem to find the right solution. Any input is greatly appreciated.

[image: keyboard is hiden]

[image: keyboard is shown]

**SOLUTION**

Added observer to viewDidLoad

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

**this was added to the class**

```
 @objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {

        guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue

        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
            tableView.contentInset = .zero
        } else {
            //Modify the top insets to 350 and the height of the keyboard > 10 ? 10 : 10
            //to eliminate the gap between the bottom cell and the textView
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 350, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame
                .height > 10 ? 10 : 10, right: 0)
        }
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableView.contentInset
    }
```

hope this helps anyone.

Comment: you can use this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager.

Comment: Share your UI how it looks when you scroll up

Comment: @Niraj_iOS screenshots added. Thank you!

Comment: Buddy you need to put `UITableView` & `UITextView` inside `UIScrollView` bind  the tableview height constraint and manage when keyboard show/hide. Hope this helps you. Let me know if need anything more.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I was able to get this going without the UIScrollView. I updated my post with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `frame` of the table view, but you should modify the `contentOffset` or `contentInsets` property.

If you move the frame, the whole table will shift offscreen, hence the top cells are also offscreen.

There a many (and with many I mean *many*) tutorials who might help you, see e.g. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-adjust-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-the-keyboard

Also multiple solutions are to be found on e.g. github.

Comment: thank you very much for this tutorial, had to modify couple things but it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me

Add this in ViewDidLoad:

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

Implement this method:

@objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {

```
    guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue

    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        tableView.contentInset = .zero
    } else {
        //Modify the top insets to 350 and the height of the keyboard > 10 ? 10 : 10
        //to eliminate the gap between the bottom cell and the textView
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 350, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame
            .height > 10 ? 10 : 10, right: 0)
    }
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableView.contentInset
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can also use [IQKeyboardManager](http://www.github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) cocoapod into your project